# How to effective resolve references in an object model after parsing an ANTLR grammar

Tags: c#, antlr4

Lets assume I'm ANTLR to parse some text to produce an readonly object model that can be consumed.  Numerous objects reference other objects in the object model.

The steps I'm currently taking are:

1. Use ANTLR 4 to parse the source into a tree (it generated)
2. Walk the tree to build a temporary object model (which uses strings as references)
3. Walk the temporary object model and create the public model

The problem with this approach is that as there is an explosion of types and mappings as the grammar grows. What approaches do compilers and other parses take to build up an object model and resolve internal references?

**Source**

Here's an excerpt of the source being parsed. Its simplified to illustrate the challenge.

```
class Class1 : Class2, Class4
{

}

class Class2 : Class3
{

}

class Class3
{

}

class Class4
{

}
```

**Public Object Model**

Here's the public object model that is the result of parsing.

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    public IModel Create()
    {
        /* Some magic */
    }
}

public interface IModel
{
    IClass CreateClass(string name);

    IEnumerable<IClass> Classes
    {
        get;
    }
}

public interface IClass
{
    void CreateGeneralization(IClass superClass);

    IEnumerable<IClass> SubClasses
    {
        get;
    }

    IEnumerable<IClass> SuperClasses
    {
        get;
    }

    IModel Model
    {
        get;
    }

    string Name
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

**Testing**

A test I wrote to validate that I got it right:

```
[Test]
public void ParseTest()
{
    // Arrange
    const string path = "MultipleInheritance.txt";
    var target = new ModelParser();

    // Act
    var model = target.Parse(path);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(model);
    Assert.IsNotNull(model.Classes);
    var class1 = model.Classes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Class1");
    var class2 = model.Classes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Class2");
    var class3 = model.Classes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Class3");
    var class4 = model.Classes.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "Class4");            
    Assert.IsNotNull(class1);
    Assert.IsNotNull(class2);
    Assert.IsNotNull(class3);
    Assert.IsNotNull(class4);

    Assert.IsTrue(class1.SuperClasses.Any(c => c == class2));
    Assert.IsTrue(class1.SuperClasses.Any(c => c == class4));
    Assert.IsTrue(class2.SuperClasses.Any(c => c == class3));
    Assert.IsEmpty(class3.SuperClasses);
    Assert.IsEmpty(class4.SuperClasses);

    Assert.IsTrue(class4.SubClasses.Any(c => c == class1));
}
```

**Grammar**

The grammar is simplified in order to illustrate the problem.

```
grammar Model;

/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

model
    :   classDeclaration*
    |   EOF
    ;

classDeclaration
    :   'class' name=Identifier  (':' generalizations=typeList)?
        '{' 
        /* attributeDeclaration* */
        '}'
    ;

typeList
    :   type (',' type)*
    ;

type
    :   name=Identifier
    ;

/*
 * Lexer Rules
 */

Identifier
    :   Letter (Letter|IdentifierDigit)*
    ;

fragment
Letter
    :   '\u0024' 
    |   '\u0041'..'\u005a' 
    |   '\u005f' 
    |   '\u0061'..'\u007a' 
    |   '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' 
    |   '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' 
    |   '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' 
    |   '\u0100'..'\u1fff' 
    |   '\u3040'..'\u318f' 
    |   '\u3300'..'\u337f' 
    |   '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' 
    |   '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' 
    |   '\uf900'..'\ufaff'
    ;

fragment
IdentifierDigit
    :   '\u0030'..'\u0039' 
    |   '\u0660'..'\u0669' 
    |   '\u06f0'..'\u06f9' 
    |   '\u0966'..'\u096f' 
    |   '\u09e6'..'\u09ef' 
    |   '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f' 
    |   '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef' 
    |   '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f' 
    |   '\u0be7'..'\u0bef' 
    |   '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f' 
    |   '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef' 
    |   '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f' 
    |   '\u0e50'..'\u0e59' 
    |   '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9' 
    |   '\u1040'..'\u1049'
    ;

WS
    :   [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip 
    ;
```

**The temporary object model**

Once parsed, I build up this model from the tree, which I then walk to build the public domain model.

```
public class TempoaryModel
{
    public TempoaryModel()
    {
        Classes = new List<TemporaryClass>();
    }

    public List<TemporaryClass> Classes
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class TemporaryClass
{
    public TemporaryClass()
    {
        SuperClasses = new List<string>();
    }

    public List<string> SuperClasses
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can avoid having a temporary model if you walk the tree twice. On first walk, create instances of classes with only their name set and add them to a dictionary(class name, IClass). On second iteration, set the references between them, using the dictionary from the first step.